# AVAudioRecorder/Player - How to tune the files recorded?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I've build a simple audio recorder as I'm to the iOS development.
But now, I still have two questions?

1.How can the recorder automatically (without buttons) detect the sound the play it later automatically either?

2.Is is possible to tune the recorded files just like **My Talking Tom Cat**?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/

try this tutorial. its really help full for you...